# Sharepoint 2010 | Detect the new user

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, user

Hello all SharePoint fanatics,

My task is:
Send e-mail to the new user when it's created in AD.

So, AD is sync with SP farm, so  I want to know, if it is possible detect, when added the new user in SP?

Or maybe ideas, how  could I deal with my task.

BR

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating users in AD? There is no event in SharePoint when a new user profile is added so you wold need to poll AD or SharePoint User Profiles for the new user. If you already have a provisioning process for your AD Users I would attach the email there.

Comment: I'm creating users directly to AD. BTW, I found solution - use ldap request fo that ;)

Comment: Sure, since you are the one creating them that makes it much easier.